# Modeling a approval process in a graph database?

Tags: graph-databases

I have an approval process I need to model as a graph and I am wondering how best to do it.
By itself, this approval process does not make much sense to model as a graph, but its connected to a bunch of other data that does, so the goal is to put all the data in the same place.

Here in MegaCorp I have a bunch of reports that need to be out the door in 5 weeks and each need to be approved by Boss A, Boss B, Boss C and finally Big Boss. Each boss *should* have the report for 1 week.

I will need to be able to answer questions like:

- Which reports are in the approval process now?
- Which reports are late now?
- Which boss caused the most delay last year?
- How many reports got out the door in the allotted time last quarter?

If it helps, this will never be a particularly large dataset.

How should I model such an approval process in a graph database?

Answer (score 0):

Graph Database should be used only if you have highly connected data with particularly large datasets.

For your problem Graph Databases can be used but will be an overkill if you are not hoping to use it as a Recommendation Engine or any other highly active graph traversing.

I think your problem can be easily modelled in a traditional RDBMS database and will be easy to maintain.

Comment: I totally agree that an RDBMS would be a better choice for such a process, but the approvals are attached to other data that is a much more obvious candidate for a graph. I've added a little clarification to that effect. Any thoughts on modelling it?

Comment: Modelling would be dependent on what Graph Database System you are hoping to use. Neo4j or any other?